# Accessing website from chrome extension when using Facebook Login

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, google-chrome-extension

I have a web platform that has users and a chrome extension written for those users to use. On the website users can register and login using email/password, facebook and G+. On the extension they can login using email/password only.

I'd like to implement Facebook and G+ login flows in the extension but they should be linked to their accounts on the website. How can this be achieved?

I thought maybe I can use FB/G+ access token as an identification measure, but I'm not sure whether the website could check if the access token is valid and of correct user.

Comment: Can't you just use the fb/g+ login in the extension and then check the return email address that you get from them if it exists in your database of registered users and if it does log that user in as if they used username/password ?

Comment: You could probably hard-code the email via developer tools and get access to any user that way.

Comment: Facebook login requires that the app runs on a specific domain, so I am not so sure if you can get that to work in an extension in the first place. Maybe if you can load a document from the actual domain “inside” the extension ... _“whether the website could check if the access token is valid and of correct user”_ - there’s an API endpoint to debug tokens, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/debugging-and-error-handling